# Is it okay to use zoom:1 in my css classes?

Tags: css, cross-browser, haslayout

Whenever I find IE is displaying my website weird (different from chrome and firefox), I try putting a `zoom:1` in the css class for the part that is being displayed weird.  A lot of the time this fixes the problem and makes it look consistent with the other browsers.

Is it a problem to use `zoom:1`?  I know my CSS won't validate, but are there any real world problems that can arise if I rely too much on using `zoom:1`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem you are fighting with this is the IE `hasLayout` issue. [Here](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) is a good article and overview on which properties also trigger "having Layout" in IE.

I know of no side-effects to `zoom: 1` except that it's not W3C valid. I'm pretty sure I'm using it myself in some projects.

However, there is of course the remote chance that `zoom` becomes a real CSS property one day - or gets used in another proprietary context like on the iPad or whatever - which could lead to things breaking.

A really *clean* solution, zoom is not. If at all possible, it's a good idea to give the element "Layout" in some other way as outlined in the article.

Comment: You can mitigate any downsides by using conditional comments to only serve the `zoom` rule to IE-7-or-lower. (IE8's layout engine works differently and tends not exhibit the same sort of problems.)

Answer (score 1):

To the contrary, there are definitive downsides to using zoom:1, even in IE.  Usually, I only include it in IE-only stylesheets, but even in the past few days I've wrestled with some layout issues because I opted to use *{zoom:1;}

-- the takeaway -- use it on a limited basis.  If you only care about IE7+, you can use min-height: 1%, which has the same effect of triggering hasLayout

Answer (score 1):

As of November 2012, it is ever more likely that zoom will someday become valid CSS, although it seems that using it in the above context should not have any negative side-effects.

See: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/ or http://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt/

Answer (score 0):

zoom is only supported by IE, so not at the moment. Potentially there could be a future property called zoom which could mess things up, but this is unlikely due to widespread usage.

Comment: Zoom is now also supported by Chrome and Safari, according to this site: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline-block;` does the same thing, but is standard code.

In the *rare* case it creates a problem, you can use

```
display: block !important; /* or inline, etc. */ 
display: inline-block; /* in this order */
```

to send it only to the ancient versions of Internet Explorer for which it's useful.