# What bug does zoom:1; fix in CSS?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have seen people apply the CSS property `zoom: 1;` on HTML elements.

Why do they do this, and what bug does it fix?

Comment: Related: [Is it okay to use zoom:1 in my css classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2784318)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This provides an internal property known as `hasLayout` in Internet Explorer versions 7 and lower.

The definitive article on the subject is here: http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

> A lot of Internet Explorer's rendering
>   inconsistencies can be fixed by giving
>   an element “layout.” In this article,
>   the authors focus on some aspects of
>   this complicated matter.
>
> “Layout” is an IE/Win proprietary
>   concept that determines how elements
>   draw and bound their content, interact
>   with and relate to other elements, and
>   react on and transmit application/user
>   events.

---

For an example of a specific bug that `zoom: 1` (and so `hasLayout`) helps to fix:

[Inline block doesn't work in internet explorer 7, 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838454/inline-block-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-6/5838575#5838575)