# Negative margin causes border to disappear in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xUrDc/

I'm trying to surround each `li` with a border exactly one pixel wide. In order that the lines meet properly, I'm setting `margin-top:-1px` on each `li` (Otherwise the border is too thick between each).

When I set my browser to IE7 in debug mode, the border at the top disappears. Can anybody tell me why this might be the case or suggest a better way to achieve the look I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ignoring the possibility of doing it a different way, you can fix IE7 by adding `zoom: 1` to `ul li`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/xUrDc/1/

Why does this work? In short, it provides a magical property known as `hasLayout` to the element in IE7, which happens to fix this bug.

More info: [What bug does zoom:1; fix in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287023/what-bug-does-zoom1-fix-in-css)

Comment: Nice, does this cause any side effects in other browsers?

Comment: In short: no. (WebKit does support `zoom`, but setting `zoom: 1` changes nothing because it's the default)

Comment: @thirtydot it seems to break when I add the `ul a` styles: http://jsfiddle.net/xUrDc/3/ (Apologies for not putting these in the question).

Comment: @Andrew: For whatever reason, you need to remove the whitespace: http://jsfiddle.net/xUrDc/4/

Comment: Wow, what? How can that make any difference?

Comment: @Andrew: It's another IE7 bug, the specifics of which I've forgotten. Another way to fix it without removing whitespace is to add `font-size: 0` on your `ul`: http://jsfiddle.net/xUrDc/5/

Comment: @thirtydot Thanks, I would never have guessed that.

Comment: @Andrew: Here's a resource talking about the bug in question: http://www.cssnewbie.com/fixing-ie6-whitespace-bug/