# Getting elements to display vertically centered in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, vertical-alignment

I can get this to work in all browsers but IE7.

#### HTML

```
<span class="verticalMiddle"></span>
                        
<span class="jArrow inlineWrapper"></span>
                        
<h2 class="inlineWrapper">What is depression?</h2>
```

#### CSS

```
.inlineWrapper {
    width: 606px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

.verticalMiddle {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
    width: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.jArrow {
    background: url(http://www.healthquestlongbeach.com/images/library/faq/arrow.png) no-repeat left top;
    height: 20px;
    width: 22px;
}

h2.inlineWrapper {
    width: 563px;
    margin-right: 13px;
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/RfRrG/5/

The problem is that the `h2` is being pushed down buy the `.verticalMiddle {height: 50px;}`, but for some reason only in IE7 (but not `.jArrow` for some odd reason).

I can fix this problem by adding

```
.inlineWrapper {display:inline;}
```

But then it breaks it in the other browsers.  Why is the text getting pushed down and how can I align it correctly?

Comment: IE 7 does not support display: inline-block property, that's your issue most probably

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display: inline-block` in IE7 only works on elements that are naturally inline.

Fortunately, there's an easy workaround. Replace this:

```
display: inline-block;
```

with this:

```
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
```

In most instances you must also [add `zoom: 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287023/what-bug-does-zoom1-fix-in-css), but it's not required in your case.

`*` is a ["safe hack"](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safe-css-hacks#safe-css-hacks) that applies the property in only in IE7 and lower.

Comment: Works great.  Out of curiosity in what situations is `zoom: 1` applicable?  All I understand about it is that it sometimes fixes IE7 bugs.

Comment: No problem. In answer to your additional question, [read this](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html#begin). It's applicable when it's applicable :)