# How do I center list items inside a UL element?

Tags: html, css

How do I center list items inside a ul without using extra divs or elements. I have the following. I thought `text-align:center` would do the trick. I can't seem to figure it out.

```
<style>
ul {
    width:100%;
    background:red;
    height:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    background:blue;
    color:white;
    margin-right:10px;
}
</style>

<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Check jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3Ezx2/1/

Answer (score 135, accepted):

write `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left`.

```
li {
        display:inline-block;
        *display:inline; /*IE7*/
        *zoom:1; /*IE7*/
        background:blue;
        color:white;
        margin-right:10px;
}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/3Ezx2/3/

Comment: i also written hack for IE7 & you can check the fiddle :)

Comment: I was about to ask the same. What is the zoom for and what does `* `represent

Comment: @refhat; about zoom:1 check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287023/what-bug-does-zoom1-fix-in-css

Comment: @Pinkie; * it's hack for IE7 check this http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml

Comment: this method is depending to `margin-right:10px;` see if it change: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ezx2/2234/

Answer (score 27):

A more modern way is to use flexbox:

```css
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;

}
ul li{
  display: list-item;
  background: black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color:white;
  margin: 0 3px;
}
div{
  background: wheat;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>  

</div>
```

Comment: Can I align for examle 2 items to left, and have still 3 items in center of page, not center of free area?

Comment: Seems it works more perfect. checked here http://jsfiddle.net/3Ezx2/2235/

Answer (score 24):

```
li{
    display:table;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 15):

Looks like all you need is `text-align: center;` in `ul`

Comment: This works in combination with `li {display:inline-block;}`

Answer (score 3):

I have run into this issue before and found that sometimes padding is the issue.

By removing padding from the ul, any li's set to inline-block will be nicely centred:

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
 width: 120px;
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

li {
 display: inline-block;
}

ul.no_pad {
 padding: 0;
}

p {
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
}

.break {
 margin: 50px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>  
  <p>With Padding (Default Style)</p>
            <ul class="with_pad">
                <li>x</li>
                <li>x</li>
                <li>x</li>
                <li>x</li>
            </ul>
  <div class="break"></div>
  <p>No Padding (Padding: 0)</p>
   <ul class="no_pad">
                <li>x</li>
                <li>x</li>
                <li>x</li>
                <li>x</li>
            </ul>
 <div>
```

Hope that helps anyone running into this same issue :)

Cheers,

Jake

Comment: thank you! this worked in firefox, all i needed to was remove the default padding the browser applies

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this:

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>

ul {
  width: auto;
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f6qgf24m/

Answer (score 2):

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    height: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

li {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the div line and it did the trick:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
<ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Pinkie asked for a solution without using div

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem slimier to yours I this quick and its the best solution I have found so far.

### What the output looks like

[Shows what the output of the code looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsaVg.png)
The borders are just to show the spacing and are not needed.

---

### Html:

```
    <div class="center">
      <ul class="dots">
        <span>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </span>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

### CSS:

```
    ul {list-style-type: none;}
    ul li{
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 2px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 5px;}
    .center{
        width: 100%;
        border: 3px solid black;}
    .dots{
        padding: 0px;
        border: 5px solid red;
        text-align: center;}
    span{
        width: 100%;
        border: 5px solid blue;}
```

---

#### Not everything here is needed to center the list items.

You can cut the css down to this to get the same effect:

```
    ul {list-style-type: none;}
    ul li{display: inline-block;}
    .center{width: 100%;}
    .dots{
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0px;}
    span{width: 100%;}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

The thing is **ul** tag comes with default margin and padding, therefore all you need to do is:

```
ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither `text-align:center` nor `display:inline-block` worked for me on their own, but combining both did:

```
ul {
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap (4) use `display: inline-flex`, like so:

```
li {
    display: inline-flex;
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Ul css

ul{
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
```

}

// ul li css

```
ul li{
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I overcame the problem with this solution.

HTML:

```
<div class="list-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
        <li>d</li>
        <li>e</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.list-wrapper {
   text-align: -webkit-center;
}
.list-wrapper ul {
    display:block;
}
```