# how to center horizontally the li elements

Tags: html, css, tabs

I am using domtab on my [site](http://exerion.comule.com/prochaine.html), but for some reasons I can't center the li elements  (the ones with ver1, ver2, TOUS LES FILMS, AFFICHAGE HORAIRE, ... written in them) or the ul block.

Here is the code relative to the domtab:

```
   #domtab_main{  
        width:600px;  
        margin:20px auto; position:relative;  



        /*height: 100px;*/
    }

    ul.domtabs{
        position: relative;
        /*float:left;*/
        /*width:100%;*/
        width: 600px;   
        /*margin : 0 auto;*/
        /*padding-left: 110px;*/    
        font-family: MS Courier New;
        font-size: 17px;    
        /*padding:0;*/
        /*text-align:center;*/


        padding: 0px;
        /*list-style: none;*/
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        left: auto;

    }
    ul.domtabs li{
        list-style:none;
        float:left;
        padding:0 .5em 0 0;
    }


    ul.domtabs a:link,
    ul.domtabs a:visited,
    ul.domtabs a:active,
    ul.domtabs a:hover{
        /*width: 170px;*/
        padding:10px;
        display:block;
        /*background:#666;
        color:#ccc;*/
        height:3em;
        /*font-weight:bold;*/
        text-decoration:none;

        color:#f0f0f0;  
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #117586 0%, #158CA1 100%);
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#117586), color-stop(100%,#158CA1));
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #117586 0%,#158CA1 100%);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #117586 0%,#158CA1 100%);
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #117586 0%,#158CA1 100%);
      background: linear-gradient(top, #117586 0%,#158CA1 100%);
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#117586', endColorstr='#158CA1',GradientType=0 );


    }


    div.domtab div{
        clear:both;
        width:auto;
        /*background:#696;*/
        color:#000;
        padding:1em 3em;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
```

What I put in comment is what I tried.
Is there a solution to this please ?

Comment: They are already aligned.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to say: to center them horizontally in the middle of the page.

Comment: what `li`s are you talking about? there are too many of them :S

Comment: the ones with ver1, ver2, TOUS LES FILMS, AFFICHAGE HORAIRE, ... written in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exact the same Problem like this: [How do I center list items inside a UL element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641251/how-do-i-center-list-items-inside-a-ul-element)

I've tested the soultion for your page.

Comment: Thanks the first level of tab is now centered ( ver1,ver2,...) but `TOUS LES FILMS` and `AFFICHAGE HORAIRE` are still at the left. I checked with firebug but there is no left,margin,padding .

Comment: It now works, I had to remove `padding:1em 3em;` from `div.domtab div`, thanks :)