# How to horizontally align three items in a navbar?

Tags: css, alignment, navbar

I am attempting to add the title of my website to the middle of my `navbar` but I haven't been able to accomplish my goal.

Here's my code:

```
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">

      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class='fas fa-bars' style='color:#66fcf1'></i> <span class='text' style='margin-left:0.5vh'>.menu</span>
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu text-light animate slideIn">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Články</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Kontakt</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">O nás</a>
      </div>

    </li>

  </ul>
<div class="align-items-center"><h5>infoot<span>.sk</span></h5></div>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])){ ?>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav justify-content-between ml-auto">
                <li class="dropdown order-1">
                    <button type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle">Login <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right mt-2">
                       <li class="px-3 py-2">
                           <form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="infoot.php">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input name="meno" id="emailInput" placeholder="Meno" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" required="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input name="heslo" id="passwordInput" placeholder="Heslo" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="password" required="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-block" name="tlacidlo">Login</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown order-2">
                    <button type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle">Register <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right mt-2">
                       <li class="px-3 py-2">
                           <form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="infoot.php">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input name="meno" id="emailInput" placeholder="Meno" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" required="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input name="heslo" id="passwordInput" placeholder="Heslo" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="password" required="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-block" name="register">Register</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
    </ul>

<?php }
else{ ?>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav  ml-auto align-items-center">
    <a class="navbar-brand"><span class='text'>.vitaj, <?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?></span></a>
    <a href="logout.php"><span class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></span></a>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
</nav>
```

What I need to align is this:

```
<div class="align-items-center"><h5>infoot<span>.sk</span></h5></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I center list items inside a UL element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641251/how-do-i-center-list-items-inside-a-ul-element)

Comment: I thought that the div was in a list, but I was mistaken. A better dup link would probably be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-an-element/114549#114549

Answer (score -1):

Wrap a **`div`** inside of another **`div`**, then give it class row, and configure the class using: **`justify-content-center`**