# What is the use of zoom:1 in stylesheets?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What bug does zoom:1; fix in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287023/what-bug-does-zoom1-fix-in-css)

If I am not incorrect, the default value for the CSS property `zoom` is `1`. And in about the last 6 or 7 online code files regarding CSS, I have seen somewhere in the code this mysterious line of code:

```
zoom: 1;
```

Is there a semantic meaning to this piece of markup? Is there a reason why they include it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using this rule is the fastest (and - usually - the cleanest) way to activate [hasLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property for an HTML element. This, in turn, affects (usually in positive way) its rendering in older versions of Internet Explorer:

> In Internet Explorer, an element is either responsible for sizing and
>   arranging its own contents, or relies on a parent element to size and
>   arrange its contents.
>
> In order to accommodate these two different concepts, the rendering
>   engine makes use of a property called `hasLayout` that can have the
>   values `true` or `false` for the element concerned. We say an element
>   gains a layout or has a layout when the `hasLayout` property has the
>   value true.1
>
> When an element has a layout, it is responsible for sizing and
>   positioning itself and possibly any descendant elements. In simple
>   terms, this means that the element takes more care of itself and its
>   contents, instead of relying on an ancestor element to do all the
>   work. Therefore, some elements will have a layout by default, though
>   the majority do not.

I'd recommend reading [this article](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/haslayout) as well (the quote is from there actually).