# Why add a star (*) to CSS rules?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

While reading the CSS code of Twitter bootstrap, I noticed that some elements have a CSS rules with a * at the beginning. For example:

```
.row-fluid {
    width: 100%;
   *zoom: 1;
}
```

Why is this technique being used?

Comment: This provides an internal property known as hasLayout in Internet Explorer versions 7 and lower.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287023/what-bug-does-zoom1-fix-in-css go this and check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignore posts about `*` being an "everything" selector, as it is, but that isn't what it is in this case.

Putting `*` before an attribute allows you to target ie7 and below. This is an old hack that shouldn't really be used as you can target ie7 and below in better ways.

[Quick explanation of how to target older IE versions](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/). If you read to the bottom you will see he explains that it is better to use conditional comments than hacks, as they are after all, hacks.

Comment: Never mind that this question is a duplicate many times over - why the hell do people keep answering `*` is the universal selector to questions that obviously are asking about an entirely different (albeit invalid) use of `*`?

Comment: @BoltClock They don't read the question properly because they are rushing to get the first answer in :P

Comment: For some technical details, [here's the Wikipedia article about CSS filters, and, in particular, the "star hack"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_hack)

Answer (score 2):

The asterisk is a hack for IE6 and IE7.

see: http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think is a hack for ie6/7