# Why does IE treat my png image differently than the other browsers?

Tags: html, asp.net, css, internet-explorer

And how can I change it? The top one is Firefox, Chrome, and Safari treat the caption background image. The bottom one is how IE treats the caption background image. [image: FireFox Example][image: IE Example]

Here is the code for the images on my web page (I use an image slide show tool I found online):

```
<a href="BlogPosts.aspx" id="iview"> <!--When making a slide show, make sure the ID property is set to "iview" -->
    <!-- Slide 1 -->
    <div data-iview:image="placeImages/FLASH1-Ephesus.jpg">
    <!-- Caption 1 -->
        <div class="iview-caption" data-x="400" data-y="400" data-transition="wipeRight" data-speed="700"><h3>The Library at Celsus</h3>Ephesus, Turkey</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Slide 2 -->
    <div data-iview:image="placeImages/FLASH2-HAGIA.jpg">
    <!-- Caption 2 -->
        <div class="iview-caption" data-x="100" data-y="400" data-transition="wipeRight" data-speed="700"><h3>Hagia Sophia</h3>Istanbul, Turkey</div></div>
    <!-- Slide 3 -->
    <div data-iview:image="placeImages/FLASH3-Bosphorus.jpg">
    <!-- Caption 3 -->
        <div class="iview-caption" data-x="400" data-y="100" data-transition="wipeRight" data-speed="700"><h3>The Bosphorus Straits</h3>Istanbul, Turkey</div></div>
    <!-- Slide 4 -->
    <div href="About.aspx" data-iview:image="placeImages/FLASH4-BlueMosque.jpg">
    <!-- Caption 4 -->
        <div class="iview-caption" data-x="400" data-y="50" data-transition="wipeRight" data-speed="700"><h3>The Blue Mosque</h3>Istanbul, Turkey</div></div>
    <!-- Slide 5 -->
    <div data-iview:image="placeImages/FLASH5-Sirince.jpg">
    <!-- Caption 5 -->
        <div class="iview-caption" data-x="100" data-y="100" data-transition="wipeRight" data-speed="700"><h3>Sirince Village</h3>Sirince, Turkey</div></div>
</a>
```

Here is the relevant code in the couple of stylesheets the slideshow tool uses:

skin 1/style.css:

```
.iview-caption {
    background: url('../../img/caption-bg.png');
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 0px;
}
```

And here is the main stylesheet for the slideshow tool:

iview.css

```
.iview-caption {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: What's setting the width of the element?  IN the code you posted there is no width set but in the live site linked below each caption has a different width set on the element itself.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was looking for. I didn't set the width. I imagine it is done dynamically of some sorts. I'm using someone else's control called the iView slide show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the text to not wrap in css.

```
.iview-caption {
    ...

    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with a .png file... the problem is the text.

Internet Explorer has subtly different rules for text positioning than some other browsers. As a result, you may want to allow a little more space for the text in your style sheet than you thought you'd need, to accommodate IE's behavior. It looks like you can just set your data-x and data-y values a little larger to fix this.

One other little trick you can try is to set [`zoom:1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287023/what-bug-does-zoom1-fix-in-css), as a way to force IE to get the sizing right and behave just a little more like other browsers.

If all else fails, you can use non-breaking spaces so that Internet Explorer has nowhere to wrap the line, like this:

```
The&nbsp;Library&nbsp;at&nbsp;Celsus
```

Comment: in this instance, the data-x and data-y attributes are the position for the caption. I'll look into trying the zoom:1 deal. Where would I put it?

Comment: As part of the css for the .iview-caption class.

Comment: ... Hmm... looking again, the `position:absolute` in that class likely already gave layout to the element. So it could be that you need a way to remove it. That could be tough. Read the material in the accepted answer of the post I linked to, and the link in that post, to find out more.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm looking. Interesting stuff. I've found that if I use a set width, I can make it tall enough to fit them, but I'd rather have it act closer to what it acts like in the other browsers, you know, lol?

Comment: You could just write your h3 caption like this: `The&nbsp;Library&nbsp;at&nbsp;Celsus` ... but I expect that would just part of the last word to be hidden.

Comment: Well, using the non breaking space made it look correct. But why?

Comment: Because now there's no place in there to put a line break. IE can't wrap the text to the next line.

Comment: You know, even if I manually set the width, it still wraps the caption. How annoying.

Comment: If you would, make a new answer with the adding of the non-breaking space and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Joseph, if you want to set the width manually, try setting `data-width` instead of just `width`.  It looks like iView will pick that up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS coditional comments to solve this.

For example, you could put this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Create an ie.css file where you'll put your custom css codes for ie.

or you could also use this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <style type="text/css">
       put your code here
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

It breaks because your caption title is broken into newline. I suggest to reset your `<h3>...</h3>` in your caption div. Also check your container width; increase it so that your caption will have more space to expand. If this cannot help, could you share us the link?

Comment: I'm not sure I can change the container width. If I can, I don't guess I know where it is. It's crazy because "caption-bg.png" is really only 5x5 pixels, but it expands to the necessary text. Check out the website [link](www.traveljoans.com) and you'll see how it expands to fit each caption.