# CSS Star Hack *

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with *zoom in IE9+ 
What is the solution for this? 
Chrome and Firefox works perfectly, but my sliders in IE not.

CSS

```
    .bx-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto 60px;
        padding: 0;
        *zoom: 1;
    }

    .bx-wrapper img {
        max-width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Hacks shouldn't be used for cross browser compatibility. Use conditionnal CSS. See: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: The `*` Hack for IE apply only to IE <= 7 http://browserhacks.com/

Comment: have a google for ie conditional stylesheets

Comment: You shouldn't need hacks for IE9. bxSlider works fine in IE9.

Comment: The `zoom: 1` fix is a hack to apply `hasLayout` to elements in old versions of IE (8 and below IIRC).  You shouldn't need it for ie9.  Also, the "star hack" is not needed for `zoom`, it's most commonly used to simulate `display: inline-block` which isn't supported in old IE (e.g. `display: block; display: *inline;`)

Comment: What is the `zoom` meant to do? In what way does it fail? Not enough info in the question.

Comment: Also, what browser mode is IE9 showing the page in? (if you're in compat mode or quirks mode, then you need to fix that before asking why individual styles aren't working)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Star hack" as you call it for the property value to IE7 and below if i'm not mistaken. Just use the normal zoom without the asterix(*).

However i would suggest you to not use the `zoom` property as it also affects the viewport. 
Also the zoom was mostly used to fix some bugs on older IE browsers: [What bug does zoom:1; fix in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287023/what-bug-does-zoom1-fix-in-css)

Instead you want to use [`transform: scale(x);`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) . This will not affect the viewport but only the element.

*Tested on IE 11*

Comment: `zoom:1` was used to trigger hasLayout in IE<=7, there's no reason to apply it to IE8+ hence the star hack.

Comment: Thanx nkmol ;) It was also a problem with my settings of IE

Answer (score 1):

Actually you shouldn't use zoom at all.
It's better to use the Transform class.

```
div {
  -webkit-transform: value;
  -moz-transform:    value;
  -ms-transform:     value;
  -o-transform:      value;
  transform:         value;
}
```

Comment: @dan you are right that you should use `transform` instead of `zoom`. You might want to explain why :) `zoom` is something different as `transform` but you should not even use `zoom` in the first place. whith `transform: scale(x);` you can get the same effect. So don't mind the others ^^

Comment: Does "transform" trigger "hasLayout" in IE5-7, though?